# Write Concern MongoDB with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I have two question;

- To set write concern my mongo connection in Sails, I've changed the journal parameter to true in node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js 
  Is it enough? (Please ignore w:1 parameter)
- Can I use node-mongodb-native driver with native keyword all specifications?